# fancyhdr: no headers for last page

Tags: fancyhdr

I was using the `fancyhdr` package to edit headers in my article, and the headers seem to work for every page except for the last. 
My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm,amssymb,scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
\fancyhead[L]{[left header]}
\fancyhead[C]{[center header]}
\fancyhead[R]{[right header]}

[some content]

\newpage
[some content]

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

What is the problem here? Whenever I add a new page, the headers for the original last page automatically show up, and the new last page still does not have any headers, although it does have the line that spans across the top of the page.
Much appreciated.

Comment: you are setting the heading inside a group which ends at the end of the evironment, before the last page is shipped out

Comment: Put a `\newpage` (or `\clearpage`/`\cleardoublepage`, whatever is appropriate) before `\end{CJK*}`

Answer (score 2):

As David mentions in the comments, you are defining the headers and footers for fancy style only inside the CJK* environment, which ends right before the end of the document.

Outside of that environment you get the default fancy style, which you haven't redefined.

I think it's best to put all the header and footer settings in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm,amssymb,scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{[left header]}
\fancyhead[C]{[center header]}
\fancyhead[R]{[right header]}

\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}

[some content]

\newpage
[some content]

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

If you want different headers and footers in portions using different languages, I would use different styles, rather than redefining `fancy`, but reserve the default style (set by the `\pagestyle` command in the preamble) for whatever you do want on the last page. (I'm happy to provide further help with that if you give more details about what you want.)

Comment: I want to use some Chinese characters I. The headers, which is why I included the /fancyhead lines inside the CJK environment. Is there any way to do this? I want the headers to be the same throughout the entire document. Thank you.

Comment: I would think you could put CJK* environments in the headers themselves, e.g., `\fancyhead[L]{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}...header contents ...\end{CJK*}}`, but if that doesn't work for you, could you edit your question to include the actual Chinese characters needed (the site supports UTF8) so we can test ourselves?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much.